# How can I safely run a GUI application inside a docker container with multiple networks?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, xauth

I am trying to access GUI of a client side of my application running inside a docker container. So far I have been using xhost + to disable access control, allowing clients to connect from any host, but this is obviously not a safe solution. I tried to solve this problem by exposing a socket and using XAuth to allow my application to use host's display but this requires my client container to be on a host network.

Here is the relevant part of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge

services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: client
    networks:
      frontend:
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: ${RUN_CLIENT}
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/usr/src/client/
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
      - ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority
    env_file:
      - ${CLIENT_ENV_FILE}
```

Client's Dockerfile contains command `RUN apt-get install -y x11-apps xauth` to install Xauth in the container. DISPLAY environment variable is passed inside of CLIENT_ENV_FILE like this `DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}`

I have tried adding `network-mode: host` key but that is incompatible with defining networks. Furthermore I have tried configuring my frontend network like this:

```
networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
    name: host
    external: true
    driver: bridge
```

which results in the following error: **network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks**.

I have found several question about this topic which were answered but none of them covered the case of multiple user defined networks.

Is there a way to use XAuth to display GUI of a client running in a container on a user defined network and if so, how?

Comment: Standard X Windows setups don't communicate over TCP, and therefore Docker networks aren't involved.  You don't need to try to configure multiple networks, nor do you need to disable Docker networking with `network_mode: host`.  For most routine things you should be able to safely delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.

Comment: (The `volumes: [/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix]` bind-mounts the Unix socket that's actually used here; the networking setup is unrelated to X's authentication system.)

Comment: I am aware that for the part posted configuring multiple networks is not necessary, but as I mentioned what is posted is only a small part of the entire docker-compose.yml file. Other services require separation.

Comment: More directly: unless you've specifically enabled a TCP listener on the X server, and you've specifically pointed `$DISPLAY` at that `hostname:0.0` address, no networking setup is involved at all.

Comment: As for the binding the xauth socket, the standard error of **couldn't connect to display ":0"** shows up. That is unless client service is on the host network.